# allow apache to run php script - audit2allow hasn't worked thus far

Tags: selinux

At a previous company the fix was to disable SELinux. I'm trying to leave SELinux enabled and tune what I need in order to accomplish my goal.

In short, I want apache/httpd to run '/usr/bin/systemctl status postfix' and return the status.  With SELinux disabled it works fine.  With SElinux enforcing it denies the action:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1518207070.317:87): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=2191 comm="sh" path="/usr/bin/systemctl" dev="dm-0" ino=100857189 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:systemd_systemctl_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1518207070.317:87): arch=c000003e syscall=4 success=no exit=-13 a0=1f32060 a1=7ffcb5925f60 a2=7ffcb5925f60 a3=7ffcb5925d90 items=0 ppid=2190 pid=2191 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="sh" exe="/usr/bin/bash" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1518207070.317:88): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=2191 comm="sh" path="/usr/bin/systemctl" dev="dm-0" ino=100857189 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:systemd_systemctl_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1518207070.317:88): arch=c000003e syscall=4 success=no exit=-13 a0=1f32060 a1=7ffcb5925f40 a2=7ffcb5925f40 a3=7ffcb5925d90 items=0 ppid=2190 pid=2191 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="sh" exe="/usr/bin/bash" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

`audit2allow -w -a` tells me numerous times:

> Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

`audit2allow -a` builds the following:

```
#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t admin_home_t:file { execute getattr };
allow httpd_t cgroup_t:dir read;
allow httpd_t cgroup_t:file { getattr open read };
allow httpd_t faillog_t:file write;
allow httpd_t init_t:dbus send_msg;
allow httpd_t postfix_etc_t:file { append getattr read };
allow httpd_t shadow_t:file { getattr open read };
allow httpd_t sudo_db_t:dir write;
allow httpd_t syslogd_var_run_t:dir read;
allow httpd_t systemd_systemctl_exec_t:file { getattr open read };
allow httpd_t systemd_unit_file_t:service status;
```

So I build the module and install it with `audit2allow -a -M postfix_status_check_by_apahce_WR`:

```
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i postfix_status_check_by_apahce_WR.pp
```

That works and I see it listed in `selmodule -l` and the audit.log errors stop, however the script never executes.

As I stated earlier, previous employment was to disable SELinux so this is new space for me.  I'm running Centos 7.3.

Before I forget, this is code:

```
<?php
     $status = shell_exec("/usr/bin/systemctl status postfix | grep Active | awk -F: '{ print $2\":\"$3 }'");
     echo $status;
    ?>
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: When I run that output through `audit2allow` all I get is `allow httpd_t systemd_systemctl_exec_t:file getattr;`. Did you omit some audit log lines?

Comment: Probably did... I'm thinking systemd_systemctl_exec_t:file might be missing execute permission from the list.

Comment: I'll run it again, to be sure I didnt.